# Multi threading directory.getfiles with lambda expression

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

1. I have two threads in c# windows services with time lapse
2. When time triggers both the thread starts simultaneously to fetch files from network server on the same folder
3. The only difference from thread1 and thread2 is the file size, thread1 takes any files less than 10mb and thread2 takes greater than 5mb.
4. So my question is, using `Directory.GetFiles` or `Directory.EnumerateFiles` will it conflict with an exception file not found, because I see that error in my log?

**thread1:**

```
foreach (var file in
    Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(serverConfig["stagingFolder"])
        .Select(s => new FileInfo(s))
        .Where(s =>
            !s.Name.StartsWith(".")
            && !s.Name.EndsWith(".tmp")
            && !s.Name.EndsWith(".stdf.gz")
            && s.Length < size))
```

**thread2**

```
foreach (string file in
    Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(serverConfig["stagingFolder"], "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .Where(s =>
            !new FileInfo(s).Name.StartsWith(".")
            && !s.EndsWith(".tmp")
            && !s.EndsWith(".stdf.gz")
            && new FileInfo(s.ToString()).Length > size))
```

Comment: Why are you using two threads? Why not one? Why not more?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), EnumerateFiles cannot fail with a FileNotFound exception. So it's the other part, where you construct the FileInfo object. Have you tried printing the path and the CWD so you can verify that the full path is present? Perhaps you need to refer to the file as `new FileInfo(serverConfig["stagingFolder"] + Path.PathSeparator + s)`

And to answer your other question, `EnumerateFiles` should be thread-safe. The docs don't say it explicitly, but there's no reason to assume `EnumerateFiles` function calls share hidden state with each other.

Comment: I am getting an error "cannot resolve symbol s" when i use your method in this way foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(new FileInfo(serverConfig["stagingFolder"] + Path.PathSeparator + s) can you give me the working loop as i am new to C#

Comment: Just change the FileInfo constructor's argument. Your version already contains `s`, so it shouldn't be out of scope.